Parsing JSON text in Deluge
I've been trying to parse this JSON text response from my GET call to Adobe Sign. All of the data comes in, but I just can't seem to grab what I need from the response and I always get an error or a null return.
Here's how the JSON comes in:
'"completed","email","role","first","last","title","company","BatteryCheckBox","BatteryPrice","CCNumber","CheckNumber","ContractCheckBox","ContractDate","ContractPrice","CustomerAddress","CustomerName","CustomerPhone","GenSerial","Other","OtherCheckbox","OtherPrice","TaxCheckBox","TaxPrice","TotalPrice","agreementId"\n"2024-05-03 05:49:11","","PREFILL","","","","","","","","","Yes","05/03/2024","$365.00","123 Bobby Dr Billyville NC 42069","Billy & Bolly Bob","(828) 674-7041","3214092309","","","","Yes","$24.64","389.64","CBJCHBCAABAAH54kOQ4geOJHlSakpV6nwOcNxQwBxLo3"\n"2024-05-03 05:50:32","billybob@ymail.com","SIGNER","Billy","Bob","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","CBJCHBCAABAAH54kOQ4geOJHlSakpV6nwOcNxQwBxLo3"\n"';

I'm trying to grab the CustomerName from this ("Billy & Bolly Bob").
Here's my code pertaining to this section:
getFormData = invokeurl
[
    url :getUrl
    type :GET
    headers:formHeaders
];
info "Form data list information: " + getFormData; 
rowlist = getFormData.toList("\n");
rowlist.remove(0);
signerMap = Map();
for each  r in rowlist
{
    info r;
        if(r.contains("SIGNER"))
        {
            signerMap.put("completed",r.get(0));
            signerMap.put("email",r.get(1));
            signerMap.put("role",r.get(2));
            signerMap.put("first",r.get(3));
            signerMap.put("last",r.get(4));
            signerMap.put("title",r.get(5));
            signerMap.put("company",r.get(6));
            signerMap.put("BatteryCheckBox",r.get(7));
            signerMap.put("BatteryPrice",r.get(8));
            signerMap.put("CCNumber",r.get(9));
            signerMap.put("CheckNumber",r.get(10));
            signerMap.put("ContractCheckBox",r.get(11));
            signerMap.put("ContractDate",r.get(12));
            signerMap.put("ContractPrice",r.get(13));
            signerMap.put("CustomerAddress",r.get(14));
            signerMap.put("CustomerName",r.get(15));
            signerMap.put("CustomerPhone",r.get(16));
            signerMap.put("GenSerial",r.get(17));
            signerMap.put("OtherCheckbox",r.get(18));
            signerMap.put("OtherPrice",r.get(19));
            signerMap.put("TaxCheckBox",r.get(20));
            signerMap.put("TotalPrice",r.get(21));
            signerMap.put("agreementId",r.get(22));
        }
}
info "Signer map information: " + signerMap;
info "Customer name: " + signerMap.get("CustomerName");

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks
I have tried many things. This code might be the closest we have come to parsing the needed information, but I'm still not getting the value returned.
